# Time Thread is stopping running

Tags: c#, multithreading, timer, timertask

I'm not finding the bug, but this thread is stopping after some time of execution, it returns a message "Thread was being aborted."

Sometimes it takes a hour, in another takes four, I can't find a patern, in some cases it never stops, but I can't find anything relate to it

```
using System.Threading;
namespace NewMVC.infraestructure
{
    public class Thread_iFood
    {
        private static bool inicializado = false;
        static Thread_iFood instance = null;
        static readonly object padlock = new object();
        private const int timer = 30000;
        static Timer thProcessaRet = new Timer(PollingIfood, null, Timeout.Infinite, Timeout.Infinite);
        private Thread_iFood()
        {
        }
        public static void Reiniciar()
        {
            inicializado = false;
            instance = null;
        }
        public static Thread_iFood GetInstance
        {
            get
            {
                if (instance == null)
                {
                    lock (padlock)
                    {
                        if (instance == null)
                        {
                            instance = new Thread_iFood();
                        }
                    }
                }
                return instance;
            }
        }
        internal static async void PollingIfood(Object obj)
        {
            try
            {
                thProcessaRet.Change(Timeout.Infinite, Timeout.Infinite);
                MetodosAuxiliares.BuscaPedidosIFood();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                LogErros.GravaLog(e, "Thread_iFood/PollingIfood");
                //here is where is stopping (Thread was being aborted.)
            }
            finally
            {
                thProcessaRet.Change(timer, Timeout.Infinite);
            }
        }
        public void Inicializa()
        {
            if (!inicializado)
            {
                inicializado = true;
                thProcessaRet.Change(timer, timer);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks like you have misunderstood how to use the singleton pattern. I would suggest making everything except `instance` non-static. Even better would be to avoid the singleton pattern altogether. You also have an `async` method without any awaits, and that is probably an error.

Comment: Also, timers invoke its callback on a thread pool thread. There is no dedicated thread to invoke events. So your claim about the thread being aborted is a bit suspicious.

Comment: There's something going on in `thProcessaRet.Change(Timeout.Infinite, Timeout.Infinite);` or `MetodosAuxiliares.BuscaPedidosIFood();` that is causing the thread to abort, but you haven't shown the source for those methods.